# Mongodb nested array aggregate

Tags: mongodb

I have this situation in my database:

*Note: all the ids are autogenerated by mongo.*

**The Hotel schema** (I have removed the extra fields for brevity)

```
hotel: Schema = 
    name: { type: String },
    rooms: [{ availabilityDates: [{ type: Date }] }]
```

The hotels has some rooms whose have an array of availability dates.

**The Order schema**

```
order: Schema 
    no: { type: String },
    hotels: [
        {
            hotel: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Hotels', required: true },
            rooms: [
                {
                    roomReferenceId: { type: String, required: true },
                    arrivalDate: { type: Date, required: true },
                    departureDate: { type: Date, required: true },
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

Any order can have one or more hotel. Every hotel in the order has it's room array with a the reference ID, and the dates.

The question is: 
How can I achieve to do a single query which aggregate both these schemas and show

- all hotels, all their rooms and availability dates
- if a room of an hotel is booked, show in some way which days are booked.

I'm open to any suggestion. I can't change the schemas because are given as is from an external contractor.

Thanks in advance for any help or tip.

Answer (score -1):

You can use **$lookup** in mongodb aggregation pipeline and join the two collections in a single query

Comment: What I dont know how to do is to join a subarray (in hotel's room) with the subarray subarray of order (order->hotels->rooms)